# random background color generator with pure javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript

```js
var color;
    
function randomColor() {
  color =  '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);  // Random number converted to hexadecimal         with toString(16) and then slice to make it a 6 digit number. like fe2e4d or f4e22e 
};

var change = document.getElementById('color_change');
change.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('random_background').style.backgroundColor  = "color" ; 
});
```

```css
div{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="random_background"></div>
<button id="color_change" >Color Change</button>
```

I think the last part is where the problem lies, but i am not able to find anywhere how to implement it correctly. Please help.

Comment: You're setting literally "color" to the property, use the variable containing the color value instead. And add a function call to `randomColor` in the click handler too. Also, instead of using the outer scope variable, return the color value from `randomColor` function, and assign it to a local variable in the click handler function.

Comment: Remove those quotes around the "color"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Teemu in the comments, you are setting a string to the `backgroundColor` property instead of setting the actual value of the `color` variable.

Here goes an example that will help you, without the use of the `var color;`
make your `randomColor()` function return the value directly. Then call that function in the `backgroundColor` property, see below:

```js
function randomColor() {
  return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8); 
};

var change = document.getElementById('color_change');
change.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('random_background').style.backgroundColor = randomColor(); 
});
```

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="random_background"></div>
<button id="color_change" >Color Change</button>
```

If you want to use the `var color`, then call `randomColor()` before set the `backgroundColor` property, and then set it as a variable, not a string:

```
...
randomColor();
document.getElementById('random_background').style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: Thanks. It may sound silly, but i was trying to get it right for so many hours.

Comment: If this helped and you want, you can mark this as accepted answer to incentivate people to always try to help you and others

Answer (score 0):

"div" has nothing height when is blank
you should initialize height to your div.

also use correct variable for color.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using random numbers for each triplet:

```
function rT(){
//random number between 0 and 255
//you could change the limits or pass a parameter to this function
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0)) + 0;
}

var change = document.getElementById('color_change');
change.addEventListener('click', function() {

  document.getElementById('random_background').style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+rT()+" "+rT()+" "+rT()+")"; });
  //in this case we use this form rgb(0-255,0-255,0-255)
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ztavxrse/

Changing the limits https://jsfiddle.net/c5j6fpnL/